# How to install jar command in Elementary OS

Tags: elementary-os

I'm using Elementary OS, and just found I've not `jar` command. I tried to install it through the "typical":

```
apt-get install jar
```

But this doesn't work, since "jar" is not found in the repositories or isn't the name of the package.

I've tried to look for it in google, but `jar` is such an used word that I've found nothing useful.

Could you say me how to install it?

Thank you in advance

**Update**:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b25)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)

$ javac -version
javac 1.8.0_40
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`jar` is part of the JDK. If you installed the JDK correctly, you should have it. As far as I'm concerned, the path to `jar` is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/jar`. The version and architecture are the main variables.

In most cases, the binary should be made available to your shell's `PATH` through a few symlinks. For instance, on my Ubuntu machine, `jar` is found at `/usr/bin/jar`, which is itself a symlink to `/etc/alternatives/jar` (another symlink). The final destination is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/jar`.

It is possible that you may not have these links correctly set up (especially if you don't use the `update-alternatives` mechanism), which might make your shell unable to find the `jar` executable. The first step to solve this is to locate it. Have a look at the various paths I've given earlier, and try to locate it.

*Note:* as a last resort, you can use the following `find` command to have it looked up system-wide:

```
$ find / -type f -name "jar"
```

Once you have found it, make sure the directory in which it lies is within your `PATH`.

For instance, let's assume you don't want to create links. If you were to add the `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin` directory to your `PATH`, you'd add the following to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin"
```

After re-sourcing the file, or reopening your terminal, you should be able to run `jar`. Now, if you don't want to use that trick, and prefer to use a symlink, you could do something like...

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/jar /usr/bin/jar
```

Of course, you'd have to make sure that `/usr/bin` is within your `PATH`, or you would just end up with the same problem all over again.

Comment: I just found the `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_40/bin/jar` before reading your answer. Of course things seems to be as you say, I'm going to do it and report news.

Comment: `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_40/bin` isn't part of your `PATH`. I'd suggest creating a link from `/usr/bin/jar` to `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_40/bin/jar` (see the end of my answer).

Comment: Yeah I know, I just did that. Thanks John.

Answer (score 3):

You need to run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre # to be able to run
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk # to be able to compile
```

For Java 8, try this out:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

To run a jar file, use this command:

`java -jar filename.jar`

Comment: But, what if I have Java JDK and JSE 1.8...?

Comment: What is `**strong text**` ? Do I have to put this too like this?

Comment: Sorry, got rid of that, but wait, you already have java installed based on your question.... What is it that you are trying to do exactly?? Are you trying to run a jar file??

Comment: Ok, I'm trying that, but are not any solution to have it without having to install it again? I've JSE 8 already...

Comment: Ok running a jar file is using the jre. I will update my answer...

Comment: No no, I mean, I need not to run, but to create it, so I need `jar` command, doesn't I? The problem is just that I've Java SE 1.8 already installed (check my update in the post) but don't have the command =S

Comment: I'd recommend either using a compiler or maven to create a jar file...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23260/discussion-between-btc-sources-and-ryekayo).

Comment: @ryekayo `jar` is part of the JDK, it is a developer tool, and shouldn't be part of the runtime (JRE). To use Maven or "a compiler," (even though I don't know what you mean there) wouldn't really solve the issue...

Comment: He wants to create a jar file, I understand you can use a compiler like Netbeans or Eclipse to do so...

Comment: @ryekayo These are IDEs, not compilers. `javac` is a compiler, and it's probably the one your IDEs rely on.

Comment: Apologies, IDE.

Comment: I've found `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_40/bin/jar` in my JDK. Why am I getting `command not found` then? o.O